# Whats the difference between some, any and returning a protocol in swift

Tags: swift

Recently i came across opaque and boxed type protocol and got a bit confused between these. So here is my doubt. Whats the difference between these 3 functions, or what are the use cases of `some`, `any` and just returning a protocol.

```swift
protocol P {
...
}

func f() -> P {
...
}

func f() -> some P {
...
}

func f() -> any P {
...
}
```